# cannot find package "firebase.google.com/go" in google cloud function

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to run some example code that stores some random data using a cloud function in the Firestore server, however, Cloud functions deploy command refuses to build the command:

```golang
// Package p contains an HTTP Cloud Function.
package p

import (
    //...
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// Store1 Stores data on FireBase
func Store1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // Use the application default credentials
    ctx := context.Background()

    conf := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "firefirefire"}
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    _, _, err = client.Collection("users").Add(ctx, map[string]interface{}{
        "first": "Ada",
        "last":  "Lovelace",
        "born":  1815,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed adding alovelace: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("ENV:" + os.Getenv("VAR1"))
    fmt.Fprint(w, html.EscapeString(d.Message))
}
```

This is what I get as an error:

```
localhost:store1 b$ ./deploy.sh
Updated property [functions/region].
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/serverlessapp/vendor/p/store1.go:6:2: cannot find package "firebase.google.com/go" in any of:
    /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/serverlessapp/vendor/firebase.google.com/go (vendor tree)
    /go/src/firebase.google.com/go (from $GOROOT)
    /tmp/sgb/gopath/src/firebase.google.com/go (from $GOPATH)
```

As you can see, the problem seems to be that Google doesn't have firebase.google.com/go on Cloud functions engine and as a result I can't have my serverless configuration do the firebase thing.
Should I move to CloudSQL and just pay the $11 fee ?
Should I continue to try to get Firebase to work?
Should I try a Firebase Function instead?
Please advise.

Comment: Felipe, you post questions that ask for other people's time. You leave the question open without selecting the correct answer. Please clean up your open questions and select the correct answers.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and codes,if I understand your issue clearly, you are trying to trigger an HTTP Cloud Function to write data into Cloud Firestore.
While you deploy the Cloud Function, package "firebase.google.com/go" cloud not be found.”. Becasue ”firebase.google.com/go” which is  the entry point to the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go).  However, Cloud Function,  [the Google Cloud Client Library for Go  is installed](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/setup#install_the_google_cloud_client_library_for_go). Based on your  requirement, It seems [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) may provide the solution you need.

Comment: I understand your answer, it is very helpful. I was kinda trying to put everything in the Google Cloud Run Docker Machine so that I can later port to a different place, I mean, I like the vendor lock in as much as the next guy. but not enough to make just everything a google dependent thing, I want to abstract the storage into a rest api so I can change it later, my concern is mostly the 50.000 read limit to be honest, I feel it may be too restrictive.